# Is there a way to consolidate multiple formulas into one

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-formula

all:

I am trying to design a shared worksheet that measures salespeople performance over a period of time. In addition to calculating # of units, sales price, and profit, I am trying to calculate how many new account were sold in the month (ideally, I'd like to be able to change the timeframe so I can calculate larger time periods like quarter, year etc').

In essence, I want to find out if a customer was sold to in the 12 months before the present month, and if not, that I will see the customer number and the salesperson who sold them.

So far, I was able to calculate that by adding three columns that each calculate a part of the process (see screenshot below):

1. Column H (SoldLastYear) - Shows customers that were sold in the year before this current month: `=IF(AND(B2>=(TODAY()-365),B2<(TODAY()-DAY(TODAY())+1)),D2,"")`
2. Column I (SoldNow) - Shows the customers that were sold this month, and if they are NOT found in column H, show "New Cust": `=IFNA(IF(B2>TODAY()-DAY(TODAY()),VLOOKUP(D2,H:H,1,FALSE),""),"New Cust")`
3. Column J (NewCust) - If Column I shows "New Cust", show me the customer number: `=IF(I2="New Cust",D2,"")`
4. Column K (SalesName) - if Column I shows "New Cust", show me the salesperson name: `=IF(I2="New Cust",C2,"")`

[image: Sample Spreadsheet]

Does anyone have an idea how I can make this more efficient? Could an array formula work here or will it be stuck in a loop since its referring to other lines in the same column?

Any help would be appreciated!!

EDIT: Here is what Im trying to achieve:
Instead of:

1. having Column H showing me what was sold in the 12 months before the 1st day of the current month (for today's date: 8/1/19-7/31/20);
2. Having Column I showing me what was sold in August 2020; and
3. Column I searching column H to see if that customer was sold in the timeframe specified in Column H

I want to have one column that does all three: One column that flags all sales made for the last 12 months from the beginning of the current month (so, 8/1/19 to 8/27/20), then compares sales made in current month (august) with the sales made before it, and lets me know the first time a customer shows up in current month IF it doesn't appear in the 12 months prior --> finds the new customers after a dormant period of 12 months.

- Im really just trying to find a way to make the formula better and less-resource consuming. With a large dataset, the three columns (copied a few times for different timeframes) really slow down Excel...

Here is an example of the end result:

[Example of final product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVrXE.png)

Comment: What do you want to improve on? You're returning four different pieces of information. How would the result look if it were consolidated into one formula? What is the desired result??

Comment: Ideally, I'd like column H, I, and J consolidated into one column. Given the size of the my table, my file is slow. Im looking for ways I can make it faster to navigate through. I figured crowdsourcing suggestions was a good idea.

Comment: Can you explain what that combined H and J column would look like? Both formulas return a CustNo. If you combine the two formulas into one column, how would you know if the returned CustNo is a new or an existing one? Please mock up the desired result. What should it look like?? Don't worry about the formula right now.